# Filenames from folder in C# xamarin forms? [Android]

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, directory, getfiles

I have a problem with get filenames from dire. I want to create mini file manager to save/read files. When I use this code
`var F = new DirectoryInfo(direPath).GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);`
, my program always return tab with 0 length.
Please help me find good method to this or other way to get filenames from eg. ExternalStorage dire.

These ways NOT WORK:

1.`Directory.GetFiles(direpath)`

2.`DirectoryInfo(direpath).GetFiles()`

3.`Directory.EnumerateFiles(direpath)`

4.`DirectoryInfo(direpath).EnumerateFiles()`

5.`Directory.EnumerateFileSystemInfos(direpath)`

6.`DirectoryInfo(direpath).EnumerateFileSystemInfos()`

My manifest with permissions:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.simplepopupform" android:installLocation="auto"> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" /> <application android:label="SimplePopupForm.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" /> </manifest>`

Comment: Android locks down all the folders your app has access to.  Your app won't have permission to look in the root folder of the device (unless you have asked for 'root' permission.  You will have to use SpecialFolder.XXX which will give you  path you can use to enumerate, but it will be limited to your application, not the whole device.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/

Comment: Neil, how i can do it?

Comment: How can you do what?   Look at the files in the root folder, look in your application's folders?

Comment: Neil, This way don't work in my app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724428/get-files-from-a-folder-that-i-have-created-in-xamarin-android this link might help you

Comment: What way won't work, and what won't it work for? What are you trying to do? Have you read docs to determine if it is possible to do, on a mobile device? Did you read the info at the link Neil gave, in his first comment? That describes what you can and can't do. `System.Environment.GetFolderPath()` is the preferred path, for files created by your app, only used by your app (not on external storage). For external storage, see [External Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage).

Comment: NOTE: Edit your question, to provide more details, to answer the questions being asked in these comments. Most importantly, explain what your GOAL is - what files you want to read, and why. How were the files created? Usually, for security, each app lives in its own private world, reading and writing its own files. Doing so is well covered in those docs. If you seek to do something else, explain the context, from the app user's perspective. What task is your app performing for the user?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with The Esstentials.FileSystem, it contains a series of helpers to find the application's cache and data directories and open files inside of the app package.

Check this document to get more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android

Comment: But i want access to files from ExternalStorage and all subdirectores

Comment: You can use dependency service to invoke native platform functionality so that you can use android code to access files.